# Armadillo c++ : use of determinant crashs

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am using armadillo with openblas dynamically linked (mingw 4.9.2r1 64bits). Armadillo is working fine.

It crashs when I call the determinant function with the "Standard" algorithm.
As I would like to use it with > 4x4 matrix, I need this algorithm.

Here is a simple example :

```
mat    A(2,2);
A(0,0) = 2; A(0,1) = 1;
A(1,0) = -1; A(1,1) = 3;

double x = arma::det(A, 'std');
```

Here is the backtrace :

```
#0  0x000000001230c5a0 in dgetf2_k () from libopenblas.dll
#1  0x0000000012308080 in dgetrf_parallel () from libopenblas.dll
#2  0x00000000120c879c in dgetrf_ () from libopenblas.dll
#3  0x0000000000411178 in arma::lapack::getrf<double> (m=0x22f798, n=0x22f794, a=0x22f710, lda=0x22f798, ipiv=0x22f6a0, info=0x22f79c) at include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:37
#4  0x000000000040f0ee in arma::auxlib::det_lapack<double> (X=..., make_copy=121) at include/armadillo_bits/auxlib_meat.hpp:665
        ipiv = {n_elem = 2, mem = 0x22f6a0, mem_local = {1, 0, 2, 0, 2291440, 0, 4279265, 0, 368698416, 0, 156489501, 0, 2291440, 0, 368225296, 0}}
        info = 1
        n_rows = 184120786
        n_cols = 2
        val = 1.1329597188418127e-317
        sign = 0
        X_copy = {<arma::Base<double, arma::Mat<double> >> = {<arma::Base_inv_yes<arma::Mat<double> >> = {<No data fields>}, <arma::Base_eval_Mat<double, arma::Mat<double> >> = {<No data fields>}, <arma::Base_trans_default<arma::Mat<double> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, n_rows = 2, n_cols = 2, n_elem = 4, vec_state = 0, mem_state = 0, mem = 0x22f710, mem_local = {2, -0.5, 1, 3.5, 1.1321929289594671e-317, 1.6982893934392007e-317, 2.120860281867698e-317, 1.0604298939010261e-317, 2.1219957904712067e-314, 1.2429334036021495e-314, 1.8216095224997325e-315, 2.7324190663050505e-315, 2.1188538812799367e-317, 1.8299493506015327e-315, 1.8216122102168459e-315, 7.8786860431775733e-313}, static is_col = <optimized out>, static is_row = <optimized out>}
        tmp = @0x347250: {<arma::Base<double, arma::Mat<double> >> = {<arma::Base_inv_yes<arma::Mat<double> >> = {<No data fields>}, <arma::Base_eval_Mat<double, arma::Mat<double> >> = {<No data fields>}, <arma::Base_trans_default<arma::Mat<double> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, n_rows = 18369900232523579118, n_cols = 18369900232523579118, n_elem = 18369900232523579118, vec_state = 4277075694, mem_state = 4277075694, mem = 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee, mem_local = {-2.6569842580370804e+303 <repeats 16 times>}, static is_col = <optimized out>, static is_row = <optimized out>}
#5  0x0000000000528d13 in ?? ()
```

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Whilst I can't reproduce the crash on my machine (g++ 4.7.2, Red Hat 6) When I compile the code I get a warning about using `'std'` as a multi-character constant. The behavior of these are implementation defined, could you try it with `"std"` (i.e. as a *string* constant) instead to see if that will make a difference?

Comment: I got the same issue. In the example, I forced the STD algorithm for example purpose (it takes another one for < 4x4 matrix). But the issue i have is only with the STD algorithm.

Comment: @Rapotor What Simon is suggesting is to use double quotes (i.e. `"`) instead of single quote (i.e. `'`) so that it reads `double x = arma::det(A, "std");`.

Comment: Yes I understood that. _I got the same issue_ with double quotes. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with standard BLAS and LAPACK instead of OpenBLAS ?

Comment: Yes, it works with the BLAS+LAPACK. By the way, I forgot to say that I am using the openblas binaries from the official sourceforce repository (0.2.14). Do you think it could be the reason? I tried to compile openblas myself but without success.

Comment: So the determinant problem looks like a bug in OpenBLAS. You may want to file a [bug report](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues) with the OpenBLAS developers.